# Tomcat's webdav repeated 401 when it's deployed on Mac OS X

Tags: java, tomcat, webdav

I have deployed tomcat 7.0.39 on a Mac OS X 10.7 with Java 1.7.0_04-b21, and turned on webdav shipped with tomcat. I try to connect it with Finder using either BASIC or DIGEST authentication, the connection fails and the tomcat's access log repeatedly reports 401 (PROPFIND /webdav/ HTTP/1.1 401 951) even if I stop the connection. But when I deploy the same tomcat on a linux machine using java 1.6, it works fine for Mac's Finder. And if I connect to the webdav deployed on Mac OS X from a browser or the linux's nautilus, everything works fine.

EDIT: the repeated 401 messages seems like infinite redirects.
EDIT2: when I connect to the webdav running on Mac OS X from OpenOffice, it's fine too. Weird.

EDIT3: In previous situation, I used localhost to connect to webdav servlet. I just changed localhost to another ip, such as 192.168.2.103, which is the same machine as localhost, Finder correctly made a connection. It's really weird. Maybe some cache interferes Finder, since I've changed the webdav's configurations of the same url several times.

Could anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The reason is unclear to me, but it's very possible that the credential cached in key chain causes this problem.

Since there was another webdav deployment of the same uri (using localhost as the server name), some authentication information might be saved to key chain for localhost. As a consequence, trying to connect to a new deployment of webdav using localhost from Finder might use the saved credential, which fails the operation. When changing localhost to another server name, no cached credential is found and the connection is successful. After I locked the key chain from Mac OS X's utility, I pointed Finder to the webdav uri. When a prompt appeared to request reading from key chain, I pressed reject button, and a dialog asking for username and password popped up. So everything goes as expected.